# Node.js assigning tasks in custom order

Tags: node.js, multiprocessing, task

I am new to nodejs programming. I am writing a program where I have a bunch of functions executing different code, however it seems as though some functions run before others and preventing other functions from running. Is there any way to make these functions run in the order of my choosing. For example:

Do task #1 - > finish -> then do task #2 -> finish - > task#3 - > etc..

Comment: You'd probably get a more satisfying answer if you added a code snippet in your question to prove your point. node.js is based on an asynchronous event loop architecture, which is why you need to be careful about the order of execution. Consider using promises or async/await keywords to put order in your execution flow.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll want to look into something called async/await

Here’s an article that explains it pretty well:
[article on async/await](https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/)

JavaScript is nonblocking so if there is work that can be done and you’re waiting on something else, like a database call, it will move on to the next task instead of waiting unless you explicitly write your program to not do so.

Also, as an FYI, the behavior you’re seeing with your current setup is called a race condition.